# Model not getting passed to controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this index view:

```
@model LeadManager.Models.ProspectingApprovalViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Approve Or Reject</h2>
<div class="form-horizontal">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="ApprovalAction" value="Approve" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input type="submit" name="ApprovalAction" value="Reject" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
</div>

//model details are below form
```

I am trying to read the model inside controller like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(ProspectingApprovalViewModel prospectingApprovalViewModel, string ApprovalAction)
{
    //access model
}
```

I can read `ApprovalAction` but the `prospectingApprovalViewModel` is null on the postback.

Why is the model not being attached?

Comment: Your form does not include any inputs for `ProspectingApprovalViewModel` (but in any case, based on the buttons - all you should be sending is the ID of the model anyway (as a route value)

Comment: Ahh OK, yes that makes sense.  I should just read ID and not send everyting over the POST request.  Thanks.  Sometimes asp.net does so much magic stuff I expect it to just work lol.

Comment: If your GET method has a parameter `int id` and your using the default routes, the all you need in the POST method is `public ActionResult Index(int id, string ApprovalAction)` (the `id` will be bound from the route vales which has been added to your forms `action` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke My model has nested entities so I have added to form like so: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NestedEntity.ID)`.  The problem with this is that in the HTML it makes the name `NestedEntity.ID`.  Variable names in C# don't allow periods so how do I create the method signature in the controller for these ID's?

Comment: Do not do that - your not editing anything so all you need in the POST method is the ID (and if you need the mdoel in the POST, then get it again based on the ID (creating all that extra html, sending it to the view and then sending it all back again unchanged just degrades performance)

Comment: Are you trying to 'Approve' or 'Reject' the nested entity? If so, then just use `@Html.BeginForm("Index", "yourController", new { id = NestedEntity.ID }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is what I am trying to do.  I am just outputting all the ID's I need into the form but Razor is outputting them like `name=NestedEntity.ID`  so then in controller I cant do `Index(int NestedEntity.ID)` because you can't have the period in the filename.

Comment: @StephenMuecke There are several nested entities, user needs to look at all the data, make sure they like it then accept or reject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127473/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-guerrilla).

Answer (score 1):

1. Your helper must be inside the form.
2. When you use two class in parameter in name of html helper must be 
   `name="className.propetyName"`.
3. When you want to post two classes you must use `ViewModel`.